# Select rows having multiple columns of same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

With a table `table1` with columns like:

```
name, dept, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

I need to find rows with same values across multiple columns - e.g. `col2, col3, col4, col5`

While something like below would work, I need an approach that would work even for large number of columns, without having to have the multiple `and` conditions.

```
select * 
from table1
where col2 = col3 and col3 = col4 and col4 = col5
```

Comment: Using `ALL` or generating sql is the simple solution. See my answer for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data..

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT id,
    trunc(random()*10) AS col1,
    trunc(random()*10) AS col2,
    trunc(random()*10) AS col3,
    trunc(random()*10) AS col4
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6)
    AS gs(id);
```

## Using `ALL`

This method is massively shorter, but you still have to type all of the column names once.

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE col1 = ALL(ARRAY[col2,col3,col4]);
```

## Dynamic sql..

```
SELECT format(
  'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE %s;',
  (
    SELECT string_agg('col1 = col'||id, ' AND ')
    FROM generate_series(2,4) AS id
  )
);
```

Comment: Using `ALL` is the way to go here. Why didn't I think of this earlier? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(ARRAY[col2, col3, col4, col5])
        ) tmp
    ) = 1;
```

The steps are broken down here:

1. Put all the columns you want to match into an array
2. Expand (Unnest) the array and remove duplicates
3. Get the count of unique values from that array
4. Filter rows where that count is 1.

Comment: what is the significance of the "tmp" here? What does it represent? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col2 IN(col3,col4,col5) OR col3 IN(col2,col4,col5) OR col4 IN(col3,col2,col5) OR col5 IN(col3,col4,col2);
```

If need any changes let me know.

Comment: This query returns rows with _some_ fields equal; OP wants rows with _all_ fields equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE ARRAY_FILL(col2, ARRAY[3]) =  ARRAY[col3, col4, col5]
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/IHGB25232)